# Error at Symfony3 : Entity of type passed to the choice field must be managed

Tags: php, symfony

When I upgraded the system running Symfony3.0 to version 3.4, the following error occured.
Since `choice_list` will not be supported due to version upgrade, `choices` I changed it to use.

**Error Code**

```
Entity of type "AppBundle\Model\Service\StaffService" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?
```

**Code**
ArticleType.php

```php
        // Contributor
        $authorChoiceList = array($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
       
        $builder->add("author", EntityType::class, array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AhiSpCommonBundle:Staff",
            "choices" => $authorChoiceList,
            "placeholder" => "Please select",
        ));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($authorChoiceList) {
            $article = $event->getData();
            $authorChoiceList->setCurrentStaff($article->getAuthor());
        });
```

ChoiceList.php

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Factory\DefaultChoiceListFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;

class StaffChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{
    private $staffService;

    private $loginStaff;

    private $currentStaff;

    public function __construct($staffService, $loginStaff)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
    }

    public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
    {
        $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff;
    }

    protected function loadChoiceList()
    {
        //Get the same shop staff as the login staff
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        // If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end
        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
        $factory = new DefaultChoiceListFactory();
        return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
    }
}
```

**Version**
Cent OS 6.7
PHP 7.3
Symfony 3.4

Comment: choice_list went away back in 3.0.  You probably just never noticed.  I suspect using choice_loader as a replacement might be better but I have not used it so that is just a guess.  However the error message is not directly related to the form.  It's complaining about an unmanaged entity which means somewhere in your code a new StaffService entity is being created.  Can't really say where.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
As you pointed out, there was an error at the stage of raising to 3.0, but it seems that you did not notice it. Apparently ChoiceList.php is the cause of the error and I'll fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just use the `query_builder` option?

see doc here -> https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

you could implement a custom method in the repository and call it inside you callable

Comment: Thank you for answering. ```query_builder``` is a query-related specification, so it doesn't seem to me much to do with this case.